# Write an evil April Fools file scanner

Tags: code-golf

This is inspired by my [python-ideas "new module loader" prank](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/pycob).

Your task is to write a cat-like program that does the following:

- Read the file on disk labeled `files`. Assume it exists. No error handling necessary.
- The file contains a list of files separated by newlines. The file names may contain spaces. Print the file name and the contents to the screen like so:

  ```
  <<<<myfile.txt
  file contents here

  <<<<another file.txt
  those file contents here
  ```

  Also store the file name some sort of array/list.
- Pick a random file name from the array and print:

  ```
  fatal error: ?
  with file myfile
  executing 'rm -rf /'
  ```

  replacing `myfile` with the randomly picked file name.
- Loop forever.

The program flow would be something like this:

```
file = open 'files'
all files = empty list
for filename in file
    print "<<<<" + filename
    contents = read contents of filename
    print contents
    add filename to all files
bad file = random filename in all files
print "fatal error: ?"
print "with file " + bad file
print "executing 'rf -rf /'"
while true do
end
```

Shortest entry wins.

Comment: Typo in the pseudocode. Shouldn't `rf -rf` be `rm -rf`?

Comment: Personally I think this toes the line of malicious code, which is [off topic here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4829/should-asking-for-malicious-code-be-on-topic). Maybe I'm just a little too jumpy when I see `rm -fr /` appear in any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Pyth - 77

Can probably be golfed a lot more.

```
#FN'"files"+*\>4Njb'NaYN)"fatal error: ?"+"with file "OY"executing 'rm -rf /'
```

Won't work on the online interpreter because it doesn't allow unsafe operations.

```
#                         Infinite loop
 FN                       For N in
  '"files"                Read file files as list of lines
  +                       Concat
   *\>4                   4 >'s
   N                      File name
  jb                      Join by newlines
   'N                     Readfile as list of lines
  aYN                     Append N to empty list
  )                       Close for loop
 "fatal error: ?"         Print message
 +                        Concatenation
  "with file "            Message
  OY                      Random choice of file list
 "executing 'rm -rf /'    Message with implicit closing quote
```